# Why is CSVParser is reading the next CSVRecord

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

Using `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser` I am having a strange behavior.

I am trying to read, line by line, a csv file delimited by `;` but my parser is skipping line for an unknown reason.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (
        File file = new File("myFile.csv");
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';'));
    ) {
        if (!parser.iterator().hasNext()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The file is empty.");
        }
        while(parser.hasNext()) { //<----- This skip a line! 
            console.log(parser.iterator().next().get(0).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

So my console looks like:

```
line2
line4
line6
line8
line10
line12
```

etc...

So my problem is that the CSVParser is skipping a line on `parser.hasNext()` and it shouldn't.

Is my code wrong?
I am pretty sure if I replace the parser with an ArrayList the iterator work as expected...
Is this a known bug? 
If yes can you guys point to a work around or a better library?

Comment: Note that it is probably more readable to use a foreach loop : `for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have it that each iteration calls `iterator()`, which returns a NEW `Iterator` .

Things are getting weird past this point, since the iterator has a `current` field storing the current record, and of course the current record of a new iterator is `null` .

In that case it calls `getNextRecord()` from CSVParser ([source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)), thus skipping a line .

If you want to stick with the iterator, just re-use the same instance :

```
Iterator<CSVRecord> iterator = parser.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) { 
    console.log(iterator.next().get(0).trim());
}
```

Comment: Yup this is working, thanks! Is this normal behavior from an iterator? Or is this just a wrong implementation?

Comment: I have no clue, but you don't have any reason to call multiple iterators to iterate over a single collection. The foreach loop `for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser)` in the comments does just that under the hood, call the iterator and iterate with it . That's also why we prefer to use foreach statements.

Comment: Can't use the foreach loop because the code I copied is split in a ItemReader in SpringBatch so I need to return only one element at a time and the "loop" is handle by SpringBatch

Answer (score -1):

Well, by default, the parser considers the first line as the header (column definition), so it is skipped in the returned records. To include this line, you must prepare your formatting accordingly, using [withSkipHeaderRecord](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withSkipHeaderRecord-boolean-).

EDIT:
Sorry, I've read too fast. I thought only first line was skipped.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't explain why it skips every second line. If it did skip only one line I would have understand but it skips every second line!